# GL_DIFFUSE turning everything yellow

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

A slightly strange problem. I'm lighting my scene with a few lights, however, if I set GL_DIFFUSE to any value at all, everything in the scene ends up yellow, be it 0, 0, 0, 0 or 1, 1, 1, 1 or any values in between. Most interestingly, if I comment out the line which sets GL_DIFFUSE, LIGHT0 ends up white (as desired) and only lighting what it's supposed to, however LIGHT1 and above end up yellow, I assume because they default to black (which I'm changing but still end up yellow). Setting LIGHT0's GL_DIFFUSE to anything also results in mass yellow. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you show some code (setup of the lights, setup of your objects' material, draw function/loop, anything else you feel might be relevant) ?

Comment: In the strangest way ever you seem to've fixed my problem.  I was moving code out of the class I'd was using as a wrapper, moving the gl calls inline to make it more readable to paste.  I compiled and ran it just to ensure that I'd not broken anything... and the problem's gone.  It's literally the same code minus two function calls, so I have no idea why, and frankly it's been such a stressful issue to debug I don't care to look into it further and find out.  All the same, thank you for the, albeit tangential, help.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you still want to post some code (if it's possible to reduce it to the main parts), we might try and see where the error was. It's always good to know what went wrong in order to prevent such errors in the future.